# Sphinx: Как правильно составить запрос?

Tags: поиск, sphinx, поисковые-системы, sphinxapi

Обнаружилась проблема на сайте. Не экранируется переменная.

```
'@name "' . $value . '"';
```

Если подавать в `value = 1"`, то выскочит ошибка

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) as `count`, 
     @groupby, IF(cetime > 1443953076, IF(cprice > 0, 2, 1), 0) AS ck 
FROM 
     aa_index 
WHERE 
    activity_id = 298 
    AND MATCH('@name "1""') 
GROUP BY company 
ORDER BY 
     ck DESC, 
     cprice DESC 
LIMIT 
     0, 100000 
OPTION 
     max_matches = 100000

index aa_index_delta,aa_index_main: syntax error, unexpected $end near ''
```

Как правильно заэкранировать переменную (`real_escape_string` deprecated), чтобы шел поиск по `1"`, или где что поправить в индексе, чтобы кавычки правильно индексировались?

П.с. заказчику принципиаален поиск по `1"`

Comment: А `1 \"` не работает?

Comment: к сожалению нет. Не работает ( ничего не находит

Answer (score 1):

от создателей Yii2-Sphinx

```
public function escapeMatchValue($str)
{
    return str_replace(
        [
            '\\',
            '/',
            '"',
            '(',
            ')',
            '|',
            '-',
            '!',
            '@',
            '~',
            '&',
            '^',
            '$',
            '=',
            '>',
            '<',
            "\x00",
            "\n",
            "\r",
            "\x1a"
        ],
        [
            '\\\\',
            '\\/',
            '\\"',
            '\\(',
            '\\)',
            '\\|',
            '\\-',
            '\\!',
            '\\@',
            '\\~',
            '\\&',
            '\\^',
            '\\$',
            '\\=',
            '\\>',
            '\\<',
            "\\x00",
            "\\n",
            "\\r",
            "\\x1a"
        ],
        $str
    );
}
```